# Different Content/Style in Multitenant Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular5, multi-tenant

What is the preferred way to go for creating a multi-tenant application with angular 4 (or above) as frontend?

I want tenant-specific content to be served via an API (like the stylesheet or a tenant-specific header/navigation) and store it in a database.

Currently, I use aspnetzero but I am stuck with the custom stylesheet. The Css is available at an Url from the backend (aspnetzero) and I get this Url from my abp session. But how do I link this css file without getting FOUC (flash of unstyled content)? Currently, I just use the link tag and set href to an angular-component variable that stores the url to my css file (it is set in ngOnInit). But then i get FOUC.

Maybe my whole architecture is wrong in my attempt. I am definitely open to entirely different approaches!

Comment: How did you solve this?